# How can i create a functional for loop to correctly calculate a double declining method depreciation?

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
        void decliningMethod() 
{
    int year=0;
    int yearI=0;
    int yearOne;
    float bookValue;
    float usefulLife;
    float endValue;
    float accuDepr = 0;
    float deprExp;
    float endBookV = 0;
    int eof = 0;
    do { 

        cout << "Enter the starting year: " << endl;
        cin >> year;                                   
        cout << "Enter book value of asset: " << endl;
        cin >> bookValue;
        cout << "Enter the useful life, in years, to calculate depreciation rate : " << endl;
        cin >> usefulLife;

        yearI = year + usefulLife;

        for (year; year<yearI; year++) {
            deprExp = 2 * ((bookValue - accuDepr) / usefulLife);
            endBookV = bookValue - accuDepr;
            cout << "year :" <<year<< endl;
            cout << "bookValue: $" <<bookValue<< endl;
            cout << "depreciation expense: $ " <<deprExp<<endl;
            cout << "Acccumulated depreciation $" << accuDepr << endl;
            cout << "ending book value: $ " << endBookV << endl;
            bookValue = endBookV;
            accuDepr += deprExp;


        }
        cout << "To end, press -1. " << endl;
        cin >> eof;
    } while (eof != -1);




    return;
}
```

Inspired by my hatred of accounting class, I'm working on a program that calculates all 3 depreciation methods for you: straight line, units of activity, and double declining. I've been successful with the rest of the program, but programming a double declining method is proving a lot more challenging , as it has more moving parts in action. The code is compiling just fine, but the for loop is not getting the correct calculations. I've been trying to debug it for hours but i keep working myself into logical circles. I just need a little push in the right direction here, please. Or am i way off the mark?

Comment: What output are you getting vs what output are you expecting? Can you please add the _mathematical_ function you are trying to calculate to your question (i.e. `f(x,y,z) = x+y+z`)? Also, since your question isn't about `cin`, it's best to hard-code your test input that produces the problem.

Comment: @ So, after a little adjusting , everything seems to be working correctly except that the "book value " is still not changing for every iteration . The math is: original book value - accumulated depreciation = ending book value. Now, for the next period, that ending book value from last period is going to be your new original book value, and repeat.